# Mysql Database tables Crashed Wordpress (Ubuntu)

Tags: mysql, database, crash, ubuntu-18.04

We have installed Mysql on Ubuntu server, and having the multiple issues,
at some times MySQL has been automatically closed i need to restart it again and again. When i check the logs of MySQL i found that there are some tables which is crashed and not repaired. so i need to know that by this issue my server's mysql is getting stopped?

Here is the error log

```
2020-04-24T14:53:43.859753Z 3 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './abc/wpdw_woocommerce_sessions' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

2020-04-24T14:53:41.320799Z 2 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './abc/wpdw_options' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
```

If anyones knows please help me resolve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: So run `REPAIR TABLE` like it says.

Comment: @Barmar I have reparied the database table and checked so many times, but after some day the table again carshes and this problem continues. Is there is any permanent solution?

Comment: [dba.se] is the place to ask for advice on this type of problem. It's not a programming question.